# Not able to connect to Redis Version 7.0.5 Using Lettuce

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster, lettuce, unsupportedoperation

Recently upgraded from Redis version 3 to Redis version 7.0.5 which is deployed on aws cloud.
Now when I try to connect to it using lettuce pool I am getting below exception.

org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Unknown redis exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.connection.PoolException: Could not get a resource from the pool; nested exception is com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Below are the dependent software versions i am using :

org.springframework.data
spring-data-keyvalue  : Version 1.2.7.RELEASE

biz.paluch.redis
lettuce   : Version 4.4.5.FINAL

org.springframework.data
spring-data-commons : Version 1.13.7.RELEASE

org.springframework.data
spring-data-redis : Version 1.8.7.RELEASE

Please help to get this sorted as I am stuck here.

Comment: I've noticed the same issue after upgrading from 7.0.4 to 7.0.5 on some deployment. Weirdly enough we did not notice any problems on another deployment of our software where the update was applied automatically.
Did you apply the update by yourself or was it deployed automatically by AWS?

Comment: Have you tried to turn it off and on again?  The manually triggered update seemed to have gone wrong somehow. We recreated the Redis cluster and everything worked again ¯\_(ツ)_/¯